# Android Threading - running a thread from another thread and waiting for a handler message

Tags: java, android, multithreading

My application uses an Executor to create threads to perform tasks.

I have a thread which loads and returns bitmaps to the main thread when needed.

If the bitmap is not found locally, another thread is used to do the download of the file.

All threads create a Looper to ensure that Handlers can be created from that thread (in case it needs to talk to another thread by sending messages to the Handler)

```
public class LooperThread extends Thread
{ 
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        Looper.prepare();
        super.run();
        Looper.loop();
    }
}
```

The main thread asks Thread-1 to get the bitmap. If the bitmap exists, it is returned successfully to the main thread. If the bitmap doesnt exist, Thread-1 asks Thread-2 to download it. A Handler is created on Thread-1 so Thread-2 can use it to tell Thread-1 when the download is complete.

The problem is that Thread-1 completes its execution and exits before the download is complete and so when Thread-2 sends a message through the handler, there is nothing to process the message.

```
final RequestHandler handler = new RequestHandler()
{
    @Override
    protected void onComplete(Object response)
    {
       //This never happens as Thead-1 is already finished when download is complete
        DownloadCompleteData data = (DownloadCompleteData)response;

        onDownloadComplete(data.success, data.downloadId, data.filePath);
    }
};

myExecutor.execute(new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        //blocking download call
        DownloadCompleteData data = download(downloadRequest);

        //Thread-2 now sends message back to Thread-1 
        handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage(COMPLETE, data));
    }
});
```

I think I need to run an infinite loop in Thread-1 so it can stay alive and keep processing messages until it is interrupted, but I'm not sure how to do this properly.

Anyone know the correct way to do it?

Comment: How does Thread-1 stop? Loopers don't stop unless you tell them to do so.

Comment: I assumed that once the thread had exited its run() method, the thread  would no longer process messages on its message loop. I dont explicitly stop the thread or the looper - threads are managed by the Executors. If the message loop is still running, then the real question is why doesn't the message sent from Thread-2 get received by Thread-1?

Comment: `Looper.loop()` is an infinite loop. Messages from the internal messagequeue are processed in that loop. So you can't wait for messages get delivered (because you wait on yourself). Not sure if that is what you do. Also have a look at [HandlerThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html) - they implement the looper logic already so you don't have to.

Comment: Hmm ok thanks. This still doesn't explain why RequestHandler.handleMessage(Message m) doesn't receive the message being sent from Thread-2. 

[RequestHandler.handleMessage calls the onComplete(Object response) method that you can see defined in the 2nd code block above] 

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to figure out why Thread-1 is exiting. Can you post the code that shows how the main thread asks Thread-1 to get the bitmap?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you want to do it this way, but you can try code similar to this in thread-1

```
if(bitmapIsntFound)
{
    Thread-2.start();
    try
    { 
        Thread-1.wait();
    }

    catch(InterruptedException e) 
    {
    System.out.println("Thread-1
    }

}
```

This will start your second thread to download the bitmap, then tell the first thread to wait while the second keeps running. After the second finishes downloading, you will want to call Thread-1.notify() to restart Thread-1.

Because you paused Thread-1 mid-stream, it will not have gone past the try{ } catch(){ } statement, so the download is guaranteed done when Thread-1 resumes, and you can just call it into the thread.